# how to use jQuery Isotope to filter jQuery Fancybox gallery

Tags: fancybox, jquery-isotope, fancybox-3

I use FancyBox and Isotope on my personnal gallery website and I discover that FancyBox shows all pictures even if they are filtered by isotope.

I have a look on different solutions:

[jQuery Isotope filtering with Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414180/jquery-isotope-filtering-with-fancybox)

[How to only show filtered images in fancybox when using isotope filters and multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575660/how-to-only-show-filtered-images-in-fancybox-when-using-isotope-filters-and-mult)

but no one works for me.

In my case, I have a js file to configure FancyBox, and FancyBox may be used without isotope, in other part of my gallery:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
 $().fancybox({
  selector : '[data-fancybox="images"]',
  loop : true,
  margin : [20, 0],
  buttons : [
   'thumbs',
   'slideShow',
   'close'
  ],
  protect : true,
  animationEffect : 'fade',
  touch : {
   vertical : false
  },
  slideShow : {
   autoStart : false,
   speed : 3000
  },
  clickContent : function( current, event ) {
   return current.type === 'image' ? 'toggleControls' : false;
  },
  clickSlide : false,
  clickOutside : false,
  dblclickContent : function( current, event ) {
   return current.type === 'image' ? 'next' : false;
  },
  caption : function( instance, item ) {
   if ($(this).find('.caption').length) {
    return $(this).find('.caption').html();
   } else {
    return $(this).attr('title');
   };
  },
  mobile : {
   thumbs : false,
   idleTime : 3,
   clickContent : function( current, event ) {
    return current.type === 'image' ? 'toggleControls' : false;
   },
   dblclickContent : function( current, event ) {
    return current.type === 'image' ? 'next' : false;
   },
   dblclickSlide : false,
  },
 });
});
```

my html and js code is a following

```html
<div class="pager">
 <div class="btn-group filters-button-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm active" data-filter="*">Toutes</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-filter=".2010">2010</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-filter=".2011">2011</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-filter=".2012">2012</button>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="isotope-wrap" class="margin-bottom-double">
 <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
 <div class="image-item image-item-height2 2010">
  <a class="thumb" href="/albums/fetes-des-lumieres-de-lyon/img_8743.jpg" title="Cathédrale Saint-Jean / 2012" data-fancybox="images">
   <img src="/cache/fetes-des-lumieres-de-lyon/img_8743_w150_h235_cw150_ch235_thumb.jpg" alt="Cathédrale Saint-Jean / 2012" class="remove-attributes img-responsive" width="150" height="235" />
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="image-item image-item-width2 2011">
  <a class="thumb" href="/albums/fetes-des-lumieres-de-lyon/img_2216.jpg" title="Fontaine Bartholdi / 2005" data-fancybox="images">
   <img src="/cache/fetes-des-lumieres-de-lyon/img_2216_w235_h150_cw235_ch150_thumb.jpg" alt="Fontaine Bartholdi / 2005" class="remove-attributes img-responsive" width="235" height="150" />
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="image-item image-item-height2 2012">
  <a class="thumb" href="/albums/fetes-des-lumieres-de-lyon/img_8709.jpg" title="Cathédrale Saint-Jean / 2012" data-fancybox="images">
   <img src="/cache/fetes-des-lumieres-de-lyon/img_8709_w150_h235_cw150_ch235_thumb.jpg" alt="Cathédrale Saint-Jean / 2012" class="remove-attributes img-responsive" width="150" height="235" />
  </a>
 </div>
 [...]
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// init Isotope after all images have loaded
var $containter = $('#isotope-wrap').imagesLoaded( function() {
 $containter.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.image-item',
  layoutMode: 'packery',
  // packery layout
  packery: {
   gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
  }
 });
});

// bind filter button click
$('.filters-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
 var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
 $containter.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// change is-active class on buttons
$('.btn-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
 var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
 $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  $buttonGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
</script>
```

what can I do to dynamicaly configure FancyBox ot display only displayed pictures filtered by Isotope?

you can see my website and my issue in action here http://www.vincentbourganel.fr/fetes-des-lumieres-de-lyon/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak your selector so it returns only visible items, example:

```
selector : '.image-item:visible > a'
```

You can use any valid jQuery selector here.

Comment: Thanks for you help!
I use " selector : '[data-fancybox="images"]' " in my Fancybox config file, because I use this selector everywhere else in my website (album without isotope, news,...).
So I need to change this selector only when I use FancyBox with isotope.
Can I overwrite the selector and how can I do that?

Comment: You could, for example, check if page has isotope and then use different selector, for example, `selector : $("#isotope-wrap").length? '.image-item:visible > a' : '[data-fancybox="images"]' `

Comment: again, thanks for your help.

for my own needs, this `selector : $("#isotope-wrap").length ? '.image-item:visible > [data-fancybox="images"]' : '[data-fancybox="images"]',` seems to work fine for me.

and it seems to be more clear like that: it is allways the same selector `[data-fancybox="images"]` but only for visible items if isotope is used.